# How to add addAcceptableStatusCodes to request with 404 value?

Tags: objective-c, afnetworking-2

I need to accept a 404 value because the API returns some JSON alerts explaining why it's giving a 404 bad Request. For that matter I need to add the following line below in order to allow it, But i still don't know where operation value comes from since its declared on the POST.

Line of Code:

```
[operation addAcceptableStatusCodes:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:404]];
```

My Source Code

```
AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
    NSDictionary *parameters = @{@"nick": @"eddwinpaz",@"pass_field":@"eeddwinpaz"};


    [manager POST:@"http://domain.com:8000/user-login/" parameters:parameters success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject)
     {
         NSLog(@"JSON: %@", responseObject);

     } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {

         NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);

         UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Login Failed"
                                                         message:@"E-mail or password are wrong, Please Try Again"
                                                        delegate:nil
                                               cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                               otherButtonTitles:nil];
         [alert show];
         [hud hide:YES];

     }];
```

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem when updating some legacy code from AFNetworking1.0 to 2.0. I found that copying the existing codes and then adding the new ones in place seemed to work.

```
NSMutableIndexSet *acceptedCodes = [[NSMutableIndexSet alloc] 
    initWithIndexSet:operation.responseSerializer.acceptableStatusCodes];
[acceptedCodes addIndex:304];
operation.responseSerializer.acceptableStatusCodes = [acceptedCodes copy];
```

Comment: Exactly how you're supposed to do it. You can, of course, go farther and create your own response serializer with custom error handling and such, but this suffices to allow certain error codes through.